# Where is the best place to suggest language enhancements to the MS Language teams?

Tags: c#, vb.net, forum, language-enhancement

Pretty much like the title says..

I'm wondering where the place is to suggest language enhancements.

A place where the VB and C# language teams hang out?

A central repository of ideas for the future of these languages?

Something like that.

Comment: @Rory - those links are blocked by my ISP filtering. If they are the equivalent of tinyurl links, can you kindly post the full links?

Comment: lol! Turns out twitter was the problem... my ISP (work related) hates twitter...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft Connect Visual Studio area](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) is probably your best bet. It's a bug/suggestion repository for all of Visual Studio, .NET and the languages.

Comment: For the benefit of Marc and others with "TinyUrl ISP" issues...the above urls are http://twitter.com/RoryBecker/status/1214883360 and http://twitter.com/RoryBecker/status/1214884328

Comment: "I figure one of the best programming learning resources on the planet has yet to be tapped"
"....someone get me an RSS feed of all the Stackoverflow.com questions that Jon Skeet or Marc Gravell has answered :)"